# How to fill multiple custom shapes with images in p5js

Tags: p5.js

I want to use a mask for multiple images and am having trouble getting that to work.  I'm trying to create the picture below. I have images that I'd like to use instead of colors. I've created a custom shape for the brown part and filled it with an image (using mask). I tried to do the same for the eyes and just overwrite the brown part, but something is not quite right (output below). Clearly I'm not quite grasping how things work.

My sketch follows. I would appreciate any pointers.

```
var blueFleece;
var brownFleece

function preload() {
    blueFleece = loadImage("https://www.onlinefabricstore.net/images/product-images/xl/121713_1.jpg");
    brownFleece = loadImage("https://images.fabric.com/images/400/400/0441363.jpg");
}



function setup() {
    createCanvas(1200, 1200);
    background('bisque');
    noLoop()
}

function draw() {

    
// Create top of head shape
  topOfHead = createGraphics(900, 600);
    topOfHead.vertex(150,  0);
    topOfHead.vertex(150,300);
    topOfHead.vertex(  0,450);
    topOfHead.vertex(150,600);
    topOfHead.vertex(300,450);
    topOfHead.vertex(600,450);
    topOfHead.vertex(750,600);
    topOfHead.vertex(900,450);
    topOfHead.vertex(750,300);
    topOfHead.vertex(750,  0);
    topOfHead.vertex(600,150);
    topOfHead.vertex(300,150);
    topOfHead.endShape(CLOSE);
// Use the shape as a mask for the image
  brownFleece.mask(topOfHead)
// Place the masked image at (0,0)
 image(brownFleece, 0, 0, 900,600)
    
// Create eye shape
    eye = createGraphics(150, 150);
  eye.vertex(75,0);
    eye.vertex(0,75);
    eye.vertex(75,150);
    eye.vertex(150,75);
    eye.endShape(CLOSE);
    blueFleece.mask(eye);
// Place the eye at (225,300)
  image(blueFleece, 225,300, 150,150)
```

}

Thanks.

[image: Cat face]
[image: Output]